# How to get table columns in display order via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to save the columns of a html table in an array via jQuery. 
I tried it like this:

```
var arr = new Array();
$("#mytable th").each(function() {
  arr.push($(this).html());
});
```

The problem is, that the columns are not in the desired order, when the table has a complex header.

Example:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">First Col</th>
      <td colspan="3">Group Col</td>
      <th rowspan="2">Fifth Col</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Second Col</th>
      <th>Third Col</th>
      <th>Forth Col</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I want the array to be like this:

```
var arr = {"First Col", "Second Col", "Third Col", "Forth Col", "Fifth Col"};
```

but it is like this:

```
var arr = {"First Col", "Fifth Col", "Second Col", "Third Col", "Forth Col"};
```

Here is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2xbaxea/1/

Is there a simple solution for getting the column names in the desired order?

Comment: can you add some more html data and explain little more??

Comment: I think, this is a pretty interesting problem you have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery get the objects that order by doing it line by line.

with the data-position attribute, we can order a personalized way.

You can try this

```
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-position="1" rowspan="2">First Col</th>
            <td colspan="3">Group Col</td>
            <th data-position="5" rowspan="2">Fifth Col</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th data-position="2">Second Col</th>
            <th data-position="3">Third Col</th>
            <th data-position="4">Forth Col</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>



    var arr = new Array();
    $("#mytable th").sort(sort_li).each(function () {
        arr.push($(this).html());
    });
    alert(arr); 

    function sort_li(a, b) {
        return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
```